# How can i go to the next/previous image lightbox using ev.target.nextElementSibling ev.targetprevElementSibling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner to web development

I have a problem with my lightbox, i need to use ev.target.nextElementSibling and ev.target.prevElementSibling to go to the next/previous image by clicking at the next arrow.png (img)/ prev arrow.png(img), i have tried everything but i don't know how. When i'm clicking at the image it's zoom in (that's ok) but when i click on the arrow the image is hidding but i want to go to the next/prev image.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img');
const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox');
const arrowNext = document.querySelector('.arrowNext');
for (let index = 0; index < imgs.length; index++) {
  const img = imgs[index];
  img.addEventListener('click', showLightbox);
}

function showLightbox(ev) {
  const prevEl = ev.target.prevElementSibling;
  const nextEl = ev.target.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(ev)
  const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox');
  const img = document.querySelector('.lightbox img');
  const imgUrl = ev.target.src;
  img.src = imgUrl;

  lightbox.classList.add('visible');
}

lightbox.addEventListener('click', hideLightbox);

function hideLightbox() {
  lightbox.classList.remove('visible');
}

arrowNext.addEventListener('click', nextPhoto);

function nextPhoto(ev) {
  const arrowNext = document.querySelector('.arrowNext');
  const img = document.querySelector('.arrowNext img');
  const imgUrl = ev.target.src;
  img.src = imgUrl;
  const next = ev.target.nextElementSibling;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.visible {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.lightbox img {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.arrowNext {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lightbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="gallery">
    <img src="/img/img1.jpg" alt="photo1">
    <img src="/img/img2.jpg" alt="photo2">
    <img src="/img/img3.jpg" alt="photo3">
    <img src="/img/img4.jpg" alt="photo4">
  </section>
  <div class="lightbox">
    <div class="arrowPrev">
      <img src="/img/prev arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <img src="/img/img5.jp" alt="">
    <div class="arrowNext">
      <img src="/img/next arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `ev.target` is the the element the mouse clicks on, in your case the arrow. You're looking to get the next image, not the next arrow.

I'd advise using an index variable to get which image is presented and then doing `document.querySelectorAll('img')[index+1]` to get the next image.

With what your code could give:

(Be aware that [`ev.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) is needed to prevent closing the lightbox when the arrow is clicked.)

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img');
const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox');
const arrowNext = document.querySelector('.arrowNext');

var index = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < imgs.length; index++) {
  const img = imgs[index];
  img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {showLightbox(e, index)});
}

function showLightbox(ev, i) {
  const prevEl = ev.target.prevElementSibling;
  const nextEl = ev.target.nextElementSibling;
  const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox');
  const img = document.querySelector('.lightbox img');
  const imgUrl = ev.target.src;
  img.src = imgUrl;
  
  index = i;

  lightbox.classList.add('visible');
}

lightbox.addEventListener('click', hideLightbox);

function hideLightbox() {
  lightbox.classList.remove('visible');
}

arrowNext.addEventListener('click', nextPhoto);

function nextPhoto(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  index++;

  const arrowNext = document.querySelector('.arrowNext');
  const img = document.querySelector('.arrowNext img');
  const imgUrl = imgs[index].src;
  img.src = imgUrl;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.visible {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.lightbox img {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.arrowNext {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lightbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="gallery">
    <img src="/img/img1.jpg" alt="photo1">
    <img src="/img/img2.jpg" alt="photo2">
    <img src="/img/img3.jpg" alt="photo3">
    <img src="/img/img4.jpg" alt="photo4">
  </section>
  <div class="lightbox">
    <div class="arrowPrev">
      <img src="/img/prev arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <img src="/img/img5.jp" alt="">
    <div class="arrowNext">
      <img src="/img/next arrow.png" alt="" style="background:red;padding:20px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```